# Why are both constructors being called?

Tags: c#, oop

In the below code I am creating an object of class B so only B's constructor should print. Why are both A and B printing?

```
namespace CodeTester
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            A a = new B();

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    class A
    {
        public A()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("A");
        }
    }

    class B : A
    {
        public B()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("B");
        }
    }

    class C : B
    {
        public C()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("C");
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
A
B
```

Comment: Because B inherits from A. Inheritance not override constructor

Answer (score 1):

Since `B` inherits from `A`, it will implicitly cast to `A`. So...

```
A a = new B()
```

Creates a new `B` object, and is then cast to an `A` object.

The reason you see an output of both "A" and "B" is that `B` is calling the `A` constructor. With parameterless constructors, it is not necessary to explicitly call `: base()`, but it is still happening, hence your output.

The base-class constructor is always called before the method body of the child class constructor. This would be more obvious to you if you had arguments in your constructors, and you would have to explicitly call `base`. As it is, C# doesn't make you write it out, and you can't "see" it.

Answer (score 1):

That is how C# works.

Since `B` inherits from `A`, your variable `a` is an instance of the class `B`, but also an instance of the class `A`.

In C#, that means that both constructors are called, in order of abstraction, from the most generic class (`A`), to the most specific one (`B`).

That's why you first get the "A" and then the "B" in your console.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It is a example of inheritance.

```
Now when you call A a=  new B();
```

In above statement actually class B object is created. What is Class B ? B is combination of A + Some of other functionality that specific to B.

Now when you create instance of B then it require whatever is in A in valid state. Like variable or some other intialization. So to do that first A get called and then B get called.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to override Constructor function in next inheritance, write like this

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            A a = new B();
        }
    }


public class A
{

    public A()
    {
        DoIt();
    }

    public virtual void DoIt()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("A");
    }
}

public class B:A
{

    public B()
    {

    }

    public override void DoIt()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("B");
    }
}
```

This output:

[image]